# How to find close of a candle and store its value in EA?

Tags: mql4

I'm new to mql4 and am confused with the basics. I want to prepare an exit strategy. Here are the conditions. If it's a buy trade and we have to sell for closing the order:

1. The candle should give a close below the Supertrend.
2. Next candle should cut the low of the previous candle.

Below is the part of the code I've prepared.

```
i=1;
if (Close[i]<st)
{
    low=close[1];
    a=checkt1();
    if (a==True)
    {
        OrderClose()
     }
}
else if(Close[i]>st)
    {
    return(EMPTY_VALUE);
    }

bool check1t()
{
    if (Ask<a && Bid<a)
        {
        CloseOrder();
        }
return True
}
```

Here the value of close keeps changing as I have set it to close[1]. Is there any function or any way that can store the value of close of the candle that had cut supertrend only? And not take up any other values?

Answer (score 0):

so you need to check that previous candle is below the one before, and that candle before closed below the indicator.

```
`void Check4closeBuy(){
   double low1 = iLow(_Symbol,0,1), low2 = iLow(_Symbol,0,2), 
   close2 = iClose(_Symbol,0,2), ind2 = iCustom(_Symbol,0,ind_name,***,buffer,2);

   if (ind2>close2 && low2>low1){
      //close here
   }
}`
```

about comparing doubles - since they are doubles not integers it is better to compare the difference below half-tick or something like that, but need to be careful with that.
so in basic case: double1>double2   ->  `double1-double2>Point/2`
but it depends on your indicator, it can have _Digits or more (like different MA may have more digits after dot then just 5).